# Different POSIX Basic Regular Expressions in find and grep?

Tags: regex, grep, gnu-coreutils

I need to use GNU *find* command in order to locate files of the pattern, described by POSIX BRE below:

```
"_[[:digit:]]*.txt"
```

(underscore followed by any number of digits followed by period followed by "txt")

When the target file names are put into single text file, I can successfully select the interested ones using *grep* with the above mentioned RE. However, *find* with --regextype posix-basic does not find any matches.

E.g.:

```
$ touch 1.txt _2.txt _3_r.txt _3.txt 3.txt
$ for i in $(ls); do echo $i >> files.txt; done
$ grep "_[[:digit:]]*.txt" files.txt
_2.txt
_3.txt
$ find . -regextype posix-basic -regex "_[[:digit:]]*.txt"
$
```

Do *grep* and *find* have different syntax for POSIX BREs? How do I then construct an RE to select the file names of interest (_2.txt and _3.txt in the example).

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless use of `ls`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) -- you mean `for i in *; do ...` or somewhat more ad-hoc `ls -1 >files.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According regex-section from `man find`:

> This is a match on the whole path, not a search.
>   For example, to match  a  file named `./fubar3',
>   you can use the regular expression `.*bar.' or `.*b.*3', but not `f.*r3'.

Answer (score -2):

Try using \d instead of [:digit:]